# Formatting a SQL query having date in where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on to automate a daily report (using one bat file) which will run a query in sql database.The query has date in where condition (which is in character format) which extracts data for previous day.Below is the sample one

```
select column 1, column2 from ABC where time like '20160822%'
```

for 22nd August data

I require assistance in formatting the query,so that the query will pull data for 1 day less when the bat file is run on the scheduled basis by making use of below query.

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), GetDate()-1,126)
```

Comment: Date handling is specific to the make and model of relational database server. Please [edit] your question to add a tag for MySQL, sql-server, Oracle, postgreSQL, or whichever server you are using.

Comment: This looks like SQL Server to me.

Comment: could you please attach the table data in the question ?

Answer (score 1):

*Never* store date information in a text column, which appears to be what you have done.  That being said, you can use a combination of `SUBSTRING` and `CONVERT` to compare your `time` column against yesterday's date.

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM ABC 
WHERE SUBSTRING(time, 1, 4) = CONVERT(char(4), GETDATE()-1, 126) AND
      SUBSTRING(time, 5, 2) = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE()-1, 126), 6, 2) AND
      SUBSTRING(time, 7, 2) = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE()-1, 126), 9, 2)
```

Comment: The Query is not returning any results.The time field is 14 character long:

Comment: Thanks Tim for prompt response.I tried the above query but it didn't fetch any results of previous date.The time field is 14 character long.Sample one is:20160824000316.So is it possible to use the trim the value and then compare.

Comment: Are you certain that you have any matching data?  Is the `time` field varchar?

Comment: -Adding more clarification to **time** column -20160824000316 YYYYMMDDHHMMSS. So is it possible to use trim here and remove the time details and put the auto decrement -1.